# Mysql select query bug with '7.56'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This seems to be a very strange issue and I can't seem to get to the bottom of the cause. When running a mysql select statement we keep getting no results returned but only when the value comes to a quoted '7.56'. if we run the same query without the quotes or using a different number it works as expected. Example queries and results below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `orders` 
WHERE  `itemsTotal` =  '7.56'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0334 sec )

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `orders` 
WHERE  `itemsTotal` = 7.56
LIMIT 0 , 30

Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0297 sec)
```

Now if you change the items total to 7.57:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `orders` 
WHERE  `itemsTotal` =  '7.57'
LIMIT 0 , 30

Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0280 sec)

SELECT * 
FROM  `orders` 
WHERE  `itemsTotal` = 7.57
LIMIT 0 , 30

Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0284 sec)
```

This is running mysql 5.5.24 for testing on local host and mysql 5.0.95 in live environment. Same results when running this query from a PHP file and phpmyadmin. If anyone can spot an obvious error, please let me know!

Comment: Could you please create an example on SQL Fiddle? that would be helpful to understand what is happening

Comment: are you sure you have the value `7.56` in `itemsTotal` field? If possible then show us at least a screenshoot of your fileds and data.

Comment: What's the datatype of ItemsTotal?
VARCHAR or Numeric (FLOAT)?

Comment: first: itemstotal gives me the urge to ask if you violated 3rd NF. Next, what datatype is itemstotal, is it a decimal/numeric field or a string?

Comment: itemsTotal is set to double(10,2) and the value of 7.56 exists as I can query for it without the quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem of your comparison is [float precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Since float data types represent values approximately, you can not rely on strict comparison in common case. That is why you can get result is you directly cast your value to string, but not if you're trying to compare floats.

So, your `7.56` is represented like `7.55999999999` for example - and can not be found via strict comparison as floats, but can be found via comparison as strings. See section ['float comparison'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html) for more information.

To solve that - usual solution is to involve precision delta and compare values with

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `orders` 
WHERE  ABS(`itemsTotal` - 7.56) < 1E-12
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

-here `1E-12` is that delta.

Comment: would this still occur itemsTotal is set to double(10,2)?

Comment: @AndrewFraser yes, since data type itself will not change (it still will be double). Numbers indicate only default output format (you'll see 10 digits before dot and 2 after dot in default mysql output).